# broadcast tv/radio genre of music

Tags: loop

Hi to all sounddesigners, a small poll for you.
 What genre of music for production elements loops do you prefer in your radio/tv sound libraries? What are more useful for you?
Let me know.
Have a nice WE
Giorgio

Answer (score 1):

It's all about what the specific project or client needs. We use online production music libraries which give easy access to a huge collection of different styles and genres, plus they are continually expanding, as the providers add more content.

Authentic sounding music with good production values in a variety of styles is what is useful from my experience. Last year I needed to use a lot of 'quirky', folky music (this is in an advertising context), but I haven't worked on any projects like that this year, so I guess it just goes to show that trends change quickly..

Comment: Like Joe, I'm usually using full tracks, rather than loops, so apologies if this doesn't directly address your question..

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mr. Bryant--I kinda need some of everything. I don't specifically use loops, so this doesn't directly answer the question...but it does depend on the particular project.